# The property has not been declared on the Type XXX Exception in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, enums

I have a file Unit.cs

```
public class Unit
{
    public UnitType UnitTypeState {get;set;}
}

public enum UnitType
{
    Folder = 0,
    Teststeps = 1,
}
```

When I put the enum definition into another class like UnitDTO I got this exception:

> The property 'UnitTypeState' is not a declared property on type 'Unit'. Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

Well thats not truee hehe the property UnitTypeState is a declared property in the Unit class class.

How can I fix that without moving the enum back to the Unit class?

**UPDATE**

I have still done some research about the bug:

"The context cannot be used while the model is being created."

The odd thing is I get this exception on a entity which is the parent of the entity with the UnitTyeState property ?!

```
using (var context = new ITMS.DataAccess.ITMSContext())
{
   return context.Templates.ToList();
}
```

so it seems the template entity is created then this exception is thrown? Or behaves EF like this: At the first DB access at all every entities or the whole model is created?

Comment: Try setting to `public partial class Unit`, if they're in the same namespace. Oh, are you doing Code-First?

Comment: No they are in different namespace Unit is Model UnitDTO is Service...

Comment: Yes I am doing code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested types are currently not supported by EF - applies to both StructuralType (i.e. entity and complex types) and enum types.

Adding a link to the EF work item that is exactly about this issue: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/119

Comment: I have some new findings about the exception, maybe you can give more guidance?

Comment: The other issue seems unrelated (looks like using the context in OnModelCreating - the context is not ready yet to be used). You would be better off creating a new thread with this question.

Comment: This OnModelCreating problem just exists since I have moved the UnitType enum from the Model to the DTO so I guess thats not a new problem.

Comment: In my Version 5.0 EF works the enum type defined in the .cs file together with a class. No Problem here. I have just moved my UnitType enum to an extra class thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following, Perhaps the enum just needs to derive from a primitive to work?

```
public enum UnitType : int
{
    Folder = 0,
    Teststeps = 1
}
```

Comment: This does not have anything to do with the underlying type. EF just does not support nested types: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/119

Comment: @Pawel Untrue at least for EF5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: by default the underlying type of enum type is int (in other words it always "derives" from a primitive type) - this is the C# default so I don't see any difference between having and not having this. EF supports only enums whose underlying type is int, byte, long, short and (AFAIR) sbyte.

Comment: btw. the video you showed does not contain nested enum types. Nested types are types that live inside another type (e.g. a class inside another class, or an enum type inside a class). Again this is currently not supported by EF.